# закрытие потока FileStream не дает вывести Image

Tags: c#, wpf

```
FileStream ReadFile = File.OpenRead(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\test.bmp");
var image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.StreamSource = ReadFile;
image.DecodePixelWidth = (int)Images.Width;
image.DecodePixelHeight = (int)Images.Height;
image.EndInit();
Images.Source = image;
ReadFile.Close(); // без этого все работает
```

без этой строчки при повторном нажатии будет ошибка не завершеных потоков

Comment: а что такое Images?

Comment: Раз принялись писать в camelCase зачем мешать с PascalCase на переменных? Чтоб читать было приятней всем остальным

Comment: попробуйте image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;

Comment: @vitidev чисто ради интереса, почему [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption?view=netframework-4.8) должно помочь?

Comment: @aepot Изображение закешируется и позволит закрыть FileStream. У меня была подобная проблема, когда блокировался файл изображения в WPF и нагуглилось именно это решение.

Comment: @vitidev но кешироваться это изображение будет все равно асинхронно. Кеш влияет только на повторное обращение к изображению. И да, ваше предложение решает некую проблему с повторным доступом к файлу, но не ту проблему, которую указал автор. Обратите внимание на последнюю часть моего ответа.

Comment: @aepot ничего не знаю про асинхронность. но в msdn в комментариях к BitmapImage.StreamSource написано "Присвойте свойству CacheOption значение BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad, если хотите закрыть поток после создания BitmapImage. "

Comment: @vitidev оп, спасибо, не заметил этого варианта, дополню сейчас ответ. В этом случае получается, что самостоятельно закрывать поток не нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы как-то слишком усложнили код.
Конструктор `BitmapImage` всё это умеет делать сам.

```cs
string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "test.bmp");
Images.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filePath));
```

Либо на основе вот [этого примера](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage?view=netframework-4.8), на случай если вам критично задать `DecodePixelWidth` и `DecodePixelHeight`.

```cs
string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "test.bmp");
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.DecodePixelWidth = (int)Images.Width;
image.DecodePixelHeight = (int)Images.Height;
image.UriSource = new Uri(filePath);
image.EndInit();
Images.Source = image;
```

Либо, если вам очень хочется использовать `FileStream`, то нужно учесть, что картинка грузится асинхронно и диспозить поток надо не раньше, чем по факту завершения ее загрузки.

```cs
string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "test.bmp");
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.StreamSource = File.OpenRead(filePath);
image.DecodePixelWidth = (int)Images.Width;
image.DecodePixelHeight = (int)Images.Height;
image.DownloadCompleted += (s, e) => (s as BitmapImage).StreamSource.Dispose();
image.EndInit();
Images.Source = image;
```

Или еще из комментариев @vitidev и [вот этой](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource?view=netframework-4.8) страницы документации я узнал, что можно сообщить `BitmapImage`, чтобы картинка загрузилась сразу, и после `EndInit()` можно было бы закрыть поток.

> Присвойте свойству `CacheOption` значение `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`, если хотите закрыть поток после создания `BitmapImage`.

```cs
string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "test.bmp");
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
{
    image.BeginInit();
    image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    image.StreamSource = fileStream;
    image.DecodePixelWidth = (int)Images.Width;
    image.DecodePixelHeight = (int)Images.Height;
    image.EndInit();
}
Images.Source = image;
```

Но я не рекомендую этот метод, так как ваш код будет ожидать полной загрузки картинки синхронно, и пока эта загрузка не завершится, приложение будет "висеть".

Comment: Не так. BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad **позволяет** закрыть поток сразу после EndInit(), но сам не закроет.

Comment: @vitidev теперь правильно?

Comment: Да. Ну разве что  image внутри using не будет виден снаружи, но то уже детали. А еще есть короткий вариант с BitmapFrame.Create. Вот тот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625428/wpf-image-control-blocks-the-file/29625691#29625691), что помог моей проблеме

Comment: @vitidev поспешил - людей насмешил. Я исправил эту мелкую оплошность. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Проблема решилась частично ошибка не вылетает но картинка не меняется после пересохранения этого файла и повторной загрузки. я с InkCanvac рисую и сохраняю картинку после мне нужна эта картинка только с отредактироваными размерами

Comment: Неплохо бы еще у `BitmapImage` вызвать в конце `.Freeze()`, тогда его вообще можно будет загружать в не-UI потоке